# In Excel, how to convert four numbers into '00:00 AM/PM' format?

Tags: excel

For example: 1330 stands for 1:30 PM and 1 stands for 00:1 AM.

I tried use function:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(INPUT,-2)/2400 + MOD(INPUT,100)/1440
```

and set cell formatting:

```
[$-en-US]h:mm AM/PM;@
```

However, 1 becomes to 12:01 PM instead of 00:1 AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"00:01 AM" is **not a real time**.

"00:01" is a real time (24-hour format), "0001" is a real time (US "Military Time" format), and "12:01 AM" is a real time (12-hour format)

- 24-hour format: from "00:00" to "23:59"
- Military Time: from "0000" to "2359"
- 12-hour format: from "12:00 AM" to "11:59 AM", then from "12:00 PM" to "11:59 PM"

You are currently trying to mix-and-match parts.  This is somewhat akin to asking why your BMW car doesn't have handlebars...

That said, if you *insist* on using this cludge, then you will need to use a Conditional Number Formatting code, such as this:

```
[<0.04166]"12:"mm" AM";hh:mm AM/PM;@
```

If the time is before 01:00, then it will display the text `"12:"`, followed by the Minutes of the Time, followed by the text `" AM"`.  Otherwise, it will display the time in correct 12-hour format

(Note that this will only work for Times **without** dates.  If you have Dates included in the field - e.g. "2020-07-30 00:01", then you will need to combine this with [Conditional Formatting](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/conditional-number-formatting/ba-p/850068) for when `Mod(A1,1)<Time(1,0,0)`, to ignore the Date portion of the time)

Also, another way to convert the number into a Time value is, appropriately enough, to use the `TIMEVALUE` function.  To convert the likes of `1` into `00:01`, you can prepend `"0000"`, take the 4 characters on the `RIGHT`, and then insert a colon - the easiest way being to `REPALCE` 0 characters:

```
=TIMEVALUE(REPLACE(RIGHT("0000" & INPUT,4), 3, 0, ":"))
```

Alternatively, you can use the `TIME` function:

```
=TIME(INT(INPUT/100), MOD(INPUT,100), 0)
```